# how to judge the abstract class with ICompilationUnit

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-jdt

I am working on the eclipse plugin development,so I find the api docs and google them,it only contains such method isClass() isInterface() with the ICompilationUnit,but I want to dig deep with the abstract class,the code like

```
public boolean isAbstract(ICompilationUnit icu) {
   //TODO
}
```

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you will need an instance of `org.eclipse.jdt.core.IType`, because one `ICompilationUnit` can contain several types. `ICompilationUnit.getTypes()` will provide you with list of all types in this unit. `ICompilationUnit.findPrimaryType()` will get you a primary type for this unit.

Your routine should look something like following:

```
public boolean isAbstract(ICompilationUnit icu) throws JavaModelException {
    final IType type = icu.findPrimaryType();
    return (type != null) 
        ? Flags.isAbstract(type.getFlags()) 
        : false;
}
```

where `Flags` is `org.eclipse.jdt.core.Flags`.

Comment: thank you max,solved according to your instruction,but I also want to ask where can you find the code snippet or the related tutorial,can you give the links?

Comment: Actually there are not much good tutorials on this subject. My current project involves JDT, so i managed to discover some tricks. In most cases you should carefully analyze the sorce code of JDT classes and their packages. As for `Flags.isAbstract()`, `Flags` class is mentioned in `ICompilationUnit.getFlags()` javadoc. Also this trick can be found somewhere on eclipse forums. http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseJDT/article.html is basic, but useful tutorial. It also contains some links.